# css style column and making responsive

Tags: html, css

So I have a css coding issues. I have two column sections on my website. I made it responsive. But on the mobile version,it makes the first left column paragraph resize to only 50% instead of filling entire width. The right column looks great.

Here is what I have in the css code:

for the column css

```
style="position: relative; margin: .5em;"
```

and for the left column I have:

```
style="width: 50%; margin-bottom: .5em;"
```

while the right column I have:

```
rightColumn {position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; width: 50%;}
```

what am I doing wrong to have the left column resize on its own like that to half the size of the full width? is there a way to fix this?

example can be found at http://internetpro.org/w/

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply media query to left column, at mobile viewport it's 50%, should be 100%. You applied this media query to right col but not to left one.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply auto-fit or switching to 100% size on that left side image.